# Getting substrings from a string in c# in the format Domain\Alias

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a variable which has strings stored in the format "domain\alias" and I want to split this in two different strings domain and alias.
I have two solutions for the above case, but none of them are working in my case.
solution 1: separating alias from the string.
for this I am using the code below:

```
 int index = name.IndexOf("\") + 1;

string piece = name.Substring(index);
```

where name is the variable which stores the string in the format "domain\alias"
This solution doesn't work for '\' however it works in case of '.'
solution 2:
separating domain from the string.
Here I got a solution below:

```
var domainFormattedString = @"fareast\v-sidmis";
var parts = domainFormattedString.Split('\\');
var domainString = parts[0]; 
return domainString;
```

this works, but it needs a string prefixed with @symbol and i have my string stored in the variable name for which this solution doesn't work.
Someone please help me to extract the two substrings from my variable name.

EDIT 1: Thanks all for your help! I figured out the issue...when i explicitly declare a string as: var x = "domian\alias" it creates and issue as \ is treated as a escape character by c# so i had to append @ at the beginning. But I got to know that when a string is read from a user, the solution works!

Comment: can someone please answer my question?

Comment: Did you try int index = name.IndexOf("\\") + 1; ?

Comment: yes i did...it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\  has a special meaning so you need to override the escape sequence to be treated as normal character with another escape character.

```
string input = @"domain\alias";
int inputindex=  input.IndexOf("\\");           
string domain = input.Substring(0, inputindex);
string alias = input.Substring(inputindex+1);
```

Hope It helps eventhough better late than never :)